# how to download an excel file from FTP server (LAN) to a local folder

Tags: vb.net

my local folder: C:\bdcrq
distant folder: C\aeromes
ip adress : 172.17.56.5
credencials : "Anonymous","Anonymous"
file name: A_MMdd.

Comment: i'm stuked for hours.please help

Comment: did you even try to google this? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-files-from-FTP-d996d604

Comment: yes i tried ,the problem that the server returns error for efry code i tried.

Comment: the second problem that i'm a begginer and i m getting tired.

Comment: any one for help?

Comment: Then post the error and what you've tried, how do you expect someone to fix a problem they do not have access to?

Comment: sorry johnny 5,the error : 407 proxy authentification required.

Comment: there's no proxy here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to your needs

```
 Sub DownloadFile()
        Dim address As String = "http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/cdk/3.1.1/en/source/MD5SUM"
        Dim locadress As String = "C:\dump\MD5SUM"
        Dim download As WebClient
        Try
            download = New WebClient
            download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(address), locadress)
            AddHandler download.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf FinishDownload
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


    Sub FinishDownload(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        Try

            '  If the request was not canceled and did not throw
            '  an exception, display the resource.
            If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then

            End If
        Finally

            '  Let the main application thread resume.
        End Try
    End Sub
```